# Child route with the same path

Tags: angular6, angular2-routing

I want to have the same route path in parent and a child module, but they overlap each other.

I have two modules:

```
AppModule (sets forRoot routes) -> AppComponent, LayoutComponent
ContentModule (sets forChild routes) -> ContentComponent
```

AppComponent.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Routes of AppModule:

```
{path: '', component: LayoutComponent}
```

LayoutComponent.html:

```
This is a layout:
<content-component></content-component>
```

Routes of ContentModule:

```
{path: '', component: ContentComponent}
```

ContentComponent.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

So basically I want the layout from `LayoutComponent` to be there always if the path starts with `/`, and then load `ContentComponent` if it's still `/`. When I add a new component in `ContentModule`, and set a new route, then on for example `/childcomponent` I want to load a new `ChildComponent` to the `router-outlet`.

Am I missing something? What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in ContentModule routes forChild and pass there a component with router-outlet. After that place there property children with array of routes.

```
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [....,
    RouterModule.forChild(ContentRoutes)
....]...
```

routes file:

```
 export const ContentRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent, children:
        [
          { path: '', component: ContentComponent },
          { path: 'another', component: AnotherComponent },
          { path: 'another2', component: Another2Component },
        ]
      }
    ];
```